# ASP.Net Web Assembly using Grpc - how to remove the last controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, grpc-c#

I am Using VS2022 and .Net 6 to create a new Blazor WebAssembly App. I then implement a Grpc Service with a simple request and response message. I am using Grpc.Web so lack of HTTP2 support shouldn't be an issue.

Since there will be no SignalR/WebSockets being used I think I'd like to remove the one and only controller in the project. I'd like the Navigation stuff to work but this isn't a deal breaker.

From the server project, remove the WeatherForecastController.cs from the controllers folder then remove the folder.
From the Shared project, remove the WeatherForecast.cs
From the Client project, replace the contents of FetchData.razor source with a grpc method and appropriate razor markup - so there are no references to the WeatherForecast object left.

I then Build->Clean Solution, close and reopen VS and then Build->Rebuild Solution

When running the solution, the server is started and the wasm client is started in a new browser instance. I see the following exception

> blazor.webassembly.js:1
> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to
> an instance of an object. System.NullReferenceException: Object
> reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router.Refresh(Boolean
> isNavigationIntercepted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView
> parameters)

I then remove the following from the server startup:

`app.UseRouting();`

I then get this error on startup:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509
> Message=EndpointRoutingMiddleware matches endpoints setup by
> EndpointMiddleware and so must be added to the request execution
> pipeline before EndpointMiddleware. Please add
> EndpointRoutingMiddleware by calling 'IApplicationBuilder.UseRouting'
> inside the call to 'Configure(...)' in the application startup code.
> Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing

It would seem that `app.UseEndpoints()` sets up middleware that assumes there is at least one controller and routing will be used.

How might I register the Grpc service without an endpoint object? Is this even possible or desirable? Any alternative approaches would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm now enabling Grpc from the app object rather than the endpoint. But haven't tried the  exercise again since there is probably something else that may need to change.     app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>().EnableGrpcWeb();